# XLRD: Start reading a column from a specific cell / range (Python)

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am trying to read all values within the first sheet of an excel file via xlrd, but I need it to start reading values from row 3 of the excel sheet, until the end of values in the column

Current version reads all information within the columns including the headers, **this is not desired**

code:

```
for col in range(sheet.nrows):
        names = sheet.cell(col,0)
        nums = sheet.cell(col,1)

        if names.value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
            if nums.value != xlrd.empty_cell.value:
                f.write('\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t'+ '<li><strong>' + names.value + '</strong> '+ repr(nums.value)+'</li>' + "\n")
```

Comment: Should be `for row in range(2,sheet.nrows):` because row numbering in `xlrd` starts at `0`.

Comment: Great point. Answer edited for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your index in the code.....  `for col in range(2,sheet.nrows):` should give the desired behaviour.

On a sidenote, you should really rename your variables, you're using col as a variable for the number of rows in a sheet (which causes all kinds of confusion).

**EDIT** to point out that XLREAD is 0 indexed.

Comment: also change `names` to `name` and `nums` to `num`

Comment: That did it! Thank you